# SP upgrade decision which method should I use

Tags: 2010, upgrade

My manager decide to upgrade to SP 2016, the current farm  is so 2010.

I read more about the migration and know that you can migrate to database attach or third party tool

My questions are how can decide to use database attach method or 3rd tool ? When should use 3ed tool?

Thanks FABIO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are some points which you should consider when planning for migrations.

1. Pre-analysis of your farm e.g. no of web applications,site collections, subsite, size of data, number of content database, how many sites are pure OOTB, how many are customized site collections. Farm solutions/sandbox solutions. client side customization, workflows tools used to automate business process etc.
2. Use the above analysis data and you might need  more than one methods for migrations. Like pure OOTB sites can be done using attach detach method. But again a catch here is that are this sites collections in separate content database ? If not you have to plan to first move to separate content database.
3. Any custom solutions deployed on sites, first needs to be build for SP 2016 and deployed/available on SP 2016 before doing migration. Or you can use third party tool to just migrate data and then install upgraded solution later.
4. How are you planning you migrate Workflows(if used external). this strategy will depend on if you 3rd party workflow tool has upgrade for SP2016 and you are planning to continue with same tool. Tool will have its own migration process, you might have to check their documentation.

There are many other points but to summarize Pre-analysis and planning of migration strategy is very important and once you do this, you would be able to decide upon which migration method to choose on case by case basis.

Hope this helps...Happy coding..!!!

Comment: Thank you if The current content DB is 2 Tera is it possible to use database attach method